# How to manually adjust display gamma on 22.04 in wayland

Tags: 22.04, xorg, wayland, gamma

I work on old HP laptop with additional monitor. After panel replacement everything was looking fine, until i connect additional monitor via DP. It's noticeable that build-in display switch rgamma to more red-ish while connecting additional monitor. Standing next to each other in join mode, displays look highly contrasting and it's quite annoying. Also rgamma tunes down when i switch to mirror mode in display settings

Excluding obvious solution, switching to X11 and use xtools witch work fine, is there way to replace `xgamma` or `xrandr` functionality in Wayland?

I've tried `ddcutil` , but build-in display via LVDS lacks DDC/CI support.